# Github action deploying to lightsail has suddenly started failing with dial tcp i/o timeout

Tags: docker, ssh, continuous-integration, github-actions, amazon-lightsail

I have a github action set up to deploy to an Amazon Lightsail server via ssh. It was working fine until it suddenly started failing with an i/o error. It has consistently failed now for 24 hours (I have tried it many times). I commented out everything in the script part and still get the error, so I know it isn't anything in the script. I think it's pretty clear that it is failing to reach the server and not even getting as far as attempting to run the script.

Here is the output:

```
Run appleboy/ssh-action@master
/usr/bin/docker run --name ea425b117d14f49c9448e1ae86bb8e0dfd290d_f25ed1 --label ea425b --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_HOST" -e "INPUT_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_KEY" -e "INPUT_PORT" -e "INPUT_SCRIPT" -e "INPUT_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_SYNC" -e "INPUT_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_HOST" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PORT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_PROXY_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_PROXY_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_SCRIPT_STOP" -e "INPUT_ENVS" -e "INPUT_DEBUG" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/carboncalc/carboncalc":"/github/workspace" ea425b:117d14f49c9448e1ae86bb8e0dfd290d

======CMD======
# cd /opt/bitnami/drupal
# git pull origin main
# composer -n install
# if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
#   exit 1 
# fi
# drush updb
# drush cr

======END======
372023/01/18 11:24:51 dial tcp 104.21.26.173:22: i/o timeout
```

Someone has reported a similar issue [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/4896) for MacOS runners but I am using `ubuntu-latest`. I've also tried with `ubuntu-20.04` and had same issue.

I can't see any way to increase the timeout so if you know of a way please let me know.

Various people have raised issues on https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action with the same issue but the answers are things like the SSH key being incorrect, the port being closed or the IP changing. But I have no problem ssh'ing from my machine, and the key that is stored in secrets is the same one that was working a few days ago.

There is plenty of disk space on the target machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. Turns out the problem was that I was using the hostname in the ssh command, rather than the IP. For some AWS-magicky reason, the hostname was resolving to an internal IP. It was different from the IP which I use when successfully SSH'ing from my local machine. So I replaced the hostname with this IP, and it started working again.